# What's a recommended way to create "live" graphic objects (for example a table) using python 3 if I use vim to write code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a (visual) table and populate it with values using a loop, but not to/as a file necessarily. I want to print out the process on the screen while it happens.

I use Vim (on Iterm2 on a Mac OSX) as my setup. New to python so I thought I'd ask here to see if there's anyone who can give me some advice. Thanks!

Comment: you're looking at a python library that does a big chunk of work for you (representing graphics, ability to scroll). Vim as the editor of your code has zero relevancy

Comment: and incase by mentioning vim you wanted to imply that the table should be displayed in the terminal then you'd need something like ncurses